# Prevent Kivy leaving debug messages

Tags: python, user-interface, debugging, terminal, kivy

I have a simple a Kivy interface that also uses the terminal.

*Example code:*

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.0.6')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text = 'Hello')

MyApp().run()
```

The problem is that whenever I start the script I get this:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Simon\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-05-12_37.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 16:07:46) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.5.13467 Compatibility Profile Context 21.19.414.1280'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ATI Technologies Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'AMD Radeon R7 Graphics'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.50'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

I have found that this is Kivy's automatic debugging messages.  How do I prevent them (or at least hide so that I can use the terminal)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As shown in the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/environment.html#configuration), you should only do the following:

```
import os
os.environ["KIVY_NO_CONSOLELOG"] = "1"

import kivy
...
```

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: Doesn't this solution suppress the traceback as well? I think the intention with this question might be in removing info messages without preventing more useful standard python debugging messages.

Comment: `os.environ["KIVY_NO_CONSOLELOG"] = "1"` stop errors from being logged as well.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can set what kind of logs you want to see by setting `Config`.
You can choose one of `trace`, `debug`, `info`, `warning`, `error` or `critical`

```py
from kivy.config import Config
# your code ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # path of the log directory
    Config.set('kivy', 'log_dir', 'your_chosen_log_dir_path')
    
    # filename of the log file
    Config.set('kivy', 'log_name', "anything_you_want_%y-%m-%d_%_.log")
    
    # Keep log_maxfiles recent logfiles while purging the log directory. Set ‘log_maxfiles’ to -1 to disable logfile purging (eg keep all logfiles).
    Config.set('kivy', 'log_maxfiles', 1000)

    # minimum log level which is what you need to not see kivy's default info logs
    Config.set('kivy', 'log_level', 'error')
    
    # apply all these changes
    Config.write()
```

Keep in mind that setting the config variables and running the program *does not immediately stop* default debug messages. You will still see them on the first run. It is because Kivy sets the config variables on the first run, then applies it from the following runs. So, you need to **run it twice** to see the effects take place.

*Setting `os.environ["KIVY_NO_CONSOLELOG"] = "1"` does remove debug messages, but it also not allows you to see error and critical messages. So setting it would not be a wise option if you want to see errors and tracebacks.*

Sources:

- Kivy's official explanation on [all config settings](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html#module-kivy.config).
- Kivy's official explanation on [Logger object](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.logger.html)