# Getting an error while opening exe : Failed to execute script , due to unhandled exception maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python-3.x, windows, kivy, pyinstaller, exe

I made a simple project on my own and it's also working fine as expected but when I'm going to converting it into .exe with pysintaller, after completion and opening the exe file it's throwing the following error as in screenshot here:

[image]

I tried various methods from the stack and also fro different blogs by setting recursion limit in .spec file and also in .py file. Also maximised the logs of kivy file and all other things but still facing the same error.

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserIconView
from kivy.core.window import Window
import datetime
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
import time
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
# Set the show_cursor property to 0 to disable the red circle on right-click
Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
import logging
# Disable Kivy logging
Config.set('kivy', 'log_level', 'error')
import os
os.environ['KIVY_NO_FILELOG'] = '1'  # eliminate file log
os.environ['KIVY_NO_CONSOLELOG'] = '1'  # eliminate console logcls

# Set the root logger's level to ERROR
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)

My_notepad_kv_string="""

<MyNotepad>
    BoxLayout:
        name: 'my_notepad'
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput: 
            id: text_input
            background_color:'#D9F59C'
            background_active:'iron_man_2.jpg'
            
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'horizontal'
            size_hint: (1, None) 
            height:50
            Button:
                text: "save_note"
                font_size : '20sp'
                on_press: root.texter(text_input.text)
                bold: True
                background_color :'#808000'
                color: '#2ADFE8'

            Button:
                text: "Clear"
                font_size : '20sp'
                bold: True
                background_color :'#811322'
                color: '#2ADFE8'
                on_release: text_input.text = ""
                


"""

class MyNotepad(Screen):

    def texter(self, text):
        self.your_text = text
        if self.your_text == "quit":
            MY_NOTES.get_running_app().stop()
        elif self.your_text != "quit":
            current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            milliseconds = int(current_time.timestamp() * 1000) % 1000
            filename = 'save_me_{}.txt'.format(
                current_time.strftime(
                    '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-{}'.format(milliseconds)))
            with open(filename, 'w') as saver:
                saver.write(self.your_text)
            self.ids.text_input.text = ""




class MY_NOTES(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(My_notepad_kv_string)
        self.icon = 'notepad_3.png'
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MyNotepad(name='my_notepad'))
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MY_NOTES().run()
```

Above is my code and the command I used for pyinstaller is

PyInstaller --onefile -w --icon=notepad.ico My_notepad_S+.py
and after following some steps like adding recursion limit in .spec file
PyInstaller My_notepad_S+.spec

But still my issue is not yet solved. I done this whole project on kivy based and try to implement it from many videos as they said. any suggest would be greatly appreciated.

may this whole log error will help please check,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1086, in emit
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1086, in emit
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1086, in emit
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1086, in emit
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kivy\logger.py", line 248, in emit
  File "kivy\logger.py", line 222, in _configure
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1446, in info
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 952, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1091, in emit
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1004, in handleError
  File "kivy\logger.py", line 338, in write
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1458, in warning
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 952, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1091, in emit
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1004, in handleError
  File "kivy\logger.py", line 338, in write
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1458, in warning
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 952, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1091, in emit
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1004, in handleError
  File "kivy\logger.py", line 338, in write
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1458, in warning
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 952, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1091, in emit
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1004, in handleError
  File "kivy\logger.py", line 338, in write
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1458, in warning
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 952, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1091, in emit
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1004, in handleError
  File "kivy\logger.py", line 338, in write
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1458, in warning
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 952, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1091, in emit
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1004, in handleError
  File "kivy\logger.py", line 338, in write
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1458, in warning
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 952, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1091, in emit
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1004, in handleError
  File "kivy\logger.py", line 338, in write
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1458, in warning
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 952, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1091, in emit
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1004, in handleError
  File "kivy\logger.py", line 338, in write
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1458, in warning
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 952, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1091, in emit
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1004, in handleError
  File "kivy\logger.py", line 338, in write
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1458, in warning
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 952, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1091, in emit
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1004, in handleError
  File "kivy\logger.py", line 338, in write
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1458, in warning
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 952, in handle
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1083, in emit
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 927, in format
  File "kivy\logger.py", line 291, in format
  File "copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
  File "copy.py", line 264, in _reconstruct
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but the [Config documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.config.html#applying-configurations) says Configuration options control the initialization of the App. In order to avoid situations where the config settings do not work or are not applied before window creation (like setting an initial window size), Config.set should be used before importing any other Kivy modules. Ideally, this means setting them right at the start of your main.py script. Try moving anything involving `Config` to the top of your `py` file.

Comment: You probably need to disable logging prior in import of the rest of kivy.  see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50308757/prevent-kivy-leaving-debug-messages

Comment: Hi @John Anderson , as you said I tried as keeping the config setting in the beginning of the file but still resulting the same issue. Could you try implementing the same in your local pc and revert me please. It'd really very helpful to me if so...

Comment: And for the inforamtion I didn't created any .env file , cause I don't know what the variable and value should be according to {import os
os.environ['KIVY_NO_FILELOG'] = '1'  # eliminate file log
os.environ['KIVY_NO_CONSOLELOG'] = '1'  # eliminate console logcls
} so , if it's the reason can you tell me which varaibles and what would be value of that should be . Si I'll do so.

Comment: Using Kivy 2.1.0, Python 3.10.4, and Pyinstaller 4.10, on windows 11, I am unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Hi , even after settings this all got many errors and I resolved it by some other steps now it's working fine. Thanks for you time and help bro....

Comment: Hi @John Anderson , I have one small query. When I run the command pyinstaller with one-file command, 'dist' named folder and main.spec file got created.But the exe file inside dist folder didn't run. So I added some lines as per the kivy documentation in main.spec file and then run the pyinstaller main.spec then in dist folder another main folder got created and inside it there were many folders and files in which .exe was there. So my question is can I run pyinstaller with one file command like Pyinstaller one file main.spec , so instead of getting many files and folders inside dist/main/..

Comment: Have a look  at the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-spec-files). Specifically, keep in mind that `When you create a spec file, most command options are encoded in the spec file. When you build from a spec file, those options cannot be changed. If they are given on the command line they are ignored and replaced by the options in the spec file.`